# Phpunit tests gives warning no tests found in class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to learn how to test with phpunit and laravel. When start the test using `phpunit` command, I am getting a warning :

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "PostsTest".

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Failures:
```

My test classname and filename matches. I have read other problems about unmatching names. my filename is `PostsTest.php` and my test file :

```
class PostsTest extends ApiTester {


    public function it_fetches_posts()

    {
        $this->times(5)->makePost();

        $this->getJson('api/v1/posts');

        $this->assertResponseOk();

    }

    private function makePost($postFields=[])
    {
        $post = array_merge([
            'title' => $this->fake->sentence,
            'content' => $this->fake->paragragraph
        ], $postFields);

        while($this->times --)Post::create($post);
    }
}
```

if necessary my ApiTester :

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class ApiTester extends TestCase {
    protected $fake;
    protected $times = 1;
    function __construct($faker)
    {
        $this->fake = Faker::create();
    }
}
```

I dont have any clue where the error is. Laravel or my local phpunit settings or anything else. Any helps is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have read the manual in laravel. and I am following the tutorial in laracasts. Am I missing any other manual ?

Comment: I understand now. In the tut video I watched the function name was used like this and It was working. I did not guess the function name shall be "testItFetchesPosts". I thought it was just an example name.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

[Annotations are the answer](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.test) (..."As an alternative to **prefixing your test method names with test...**")

```
/** @test */
public function it_tests_something()
{
  ...
}
```

Adding that `@test` tells phpunit to treat the function as a test, regardless of the name.

Comment: Doh! totally forgot about this.

Answer (score 115):

The only methods that PHPUnit will recognize as tests are those with names [starting with **test**](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

So you should rename the `it_fetches_posts()` method to `test_it_fetches_posts` or  `testItFetchesPosts`. The camel case naming is optional but useful if you use the --testdox option later.

Also, as stated in other answer you can also add the `@test` annotation to any method and it will be considered a test by PHPUnit.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I started to get the results . I guess tutorial became obsolete.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as an annotation `/** @test */` instructs phpunit to treat any indicated method as a test

Comment: Also, ensure your test method is public, phpunit won't recognize private methods.

Answer (score 16):

Either begin its name with word 'test' like `test_something_should_work` or update the test docs with this annotation `/** @test */`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, consider a case where you are testing a class `A` that requires a class `B` (that you will mock). When `$a->someMethod($mocked_B_class)` is called, make sure you don't have any warnings in it such as trying to access a property of an array like you would access the property of a class `($array = ['one','two']; $array->one)`.

In this case it wont give you any information about the test or the error